# Unable to connect using pymssql with windows authentication

Tags: python, database-connection, pymssql

While trying to connect to MSSQL Server 2012 using pymssql, I get the following error.

My server name in Windows Authentication is SARATH,User Name is Sarath\SarathShanker and I did not set a password.

Code:

```
mssql_conn=pymssql.connect(host='SARATH',user='Sarath\SarathShanker',password='',database='matrix')
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   File "pymssql.pyx", line 556, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:7990)
>
> pymssql.OperationalError: (18452, 'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted
>   domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.DB-Lib error message 18452
>   , severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB
>   -Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed\nDB-Lib
>   error message 18452, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages fro
>   m the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server conne
>   ction failed\n')

How should I modify my script in order to connect to MSSQL Server using pymssql.

P.S I have already imported pymssql as well. *(Not Shown in Code above)*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`conn = pymssql.connect(host='myhost', database='mydb')`

This is with Python Version 3.4 and for Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If on RHEL, try

```
os.environ["FREETDSCONF"] = "/etc/freetds.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of pymssql (I use 2.1.3),

```
pymssql.connect(server='<TEST_SERVER>', database='<TEST_DB>')
```

Simply replace the '' and '' with your server and DB name.